# In this Javascript function why does alert(multi) alert the value '3'

Tags: javascript

Calling multiMax() at the bottom of the code block we pass in 4 arguments. I see how the rest of the logic plays out I just don't get why alert(multi) is equal to '3';

http://jsfiddle.net/captainill/AjEPV/

```
function multiMax(multi){
  alert(multi);
  // Make an array of all but the first argument 
  var allButFirst = Array().slice.call( arguments, 1 ); 

  // Find the largest number in that array of arguments 
  var largestAllButFirst = Math.max.apply( Math, allButFirst );

  // Return the multiplied result 
  return multi * largestAllButFirst; 
} 
alert( multiMax(3, 1, 2, 3) == 9, "3*3=9 (First arg, by largest.)" );
```

I've been going through these excellent little tutorials:
http://ejohn.org/apps/learn/#47

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`alert(multi)` displays "3" because `multi` is the first argument, and 3 is the first value you're passing to the function.

Comment: +1 Simple and concise. The other arguments are accessed as an array through the `arguments` keyword and are not explicitly named.

Comment: Don't know why I didn't grasp this but I appreciate the answer. Makes complete sense.

Answer (score 2):

`alert(multi)` displays "3" because you are passing 3 as the first value into the `multiMax` Function.

Replace this line.

```
alert( multiMax(3, 1, 2, 3) == 9, "3*3=9 (First arg, by largest.)" );
```

With

```
alert( multiMax(4, 1, 2, 3) == 9, "3*3=9 (First arg, by largest.)" );
```

And the result will be 4, notice the difference between the two lines.

Comment: +1 For the example. However, it leaves a little to be desired on the argument-binding explanation :(

Answer (score 0):

`ASSERT` and `ALERT` are NOT the same thing.

I don't think the `alert` call is the real issue here. `alert` only prints/displays the first value -> in your case `alert( multimax(3, 1,2,3) == 9, "Whatever")` has a first parameter of `multimax(3,1,2,3)==9`, which as we can all see is `true`. So that is why you get `true` as opposed to "3*3 == 9".

Comment: The "issue" is caused by the `alert` in the function, before the return, from what I can tell.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood the question a bit then. I was just trying to explain why he was getting 'different' output from the example page he posted.